# Android DJI SDK - My App Bundle installed from Play Store hangs an otherwise perfectly working app

Tags: android, dji-sdk

So I've been dealing with this problem for years - if I build my DJI-compatible app as an APK, and submit it to the Play Store, it works fine. If I build the same app as an App Bundle, and submit it to the Play Store, then when I install and run that app, the whole thing hangs / crashes.

It's been possible using `bundletool` to replicate this issue with local builds, so I don't have to use the Play Store as a debugging platform (!!), but until now I've not been able to actually solve the problem. The hang seems to occur after calling `DJISDKManager::registerApp()`.

I got around this by releasing split APKs instead. But now two things have made this more urgent for me:

1. Google are getting tighter and tigher on their requirements for using App Bundles (at least for new apps)
2. With the latest DJI SDK (4.15 at time of writing) my app APKs are now above the 100MB limit

So it's gotta be App Bundles. What's missing to make these functional?

Answer (score 0):

I'm answering myself since this solution seems to have been helpful while buried in the DJI Mobile SDK Github Issues pages, maybe it's helpful here too.

By adding the line

```
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
```

to `gradle.properties`, app bundle packaging seems to work fine now.

References: [Issue 982](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/982), [Issue 642](https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-Android/issues/642)

---

Note in Issue 642, people have also added

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
```

to their `AndroidManifest.xml` - this may be helpful; in my case this was already in place in my code to fix a different issue, so I couldn't say if it's required or not for this problem.